# Default value for a nested map in clojure

Tags: clojure, functional-programming

I have been looking into clojure for a while now, but I couldnt find a function which would supply a default value for a nested map. for example if I have a map as below,

```
(def paths {:A {:B 5, :D 5, :E 7},
            :B {:C 4},
            :C {:D 8, :E 2},
            :D {:C 8, :E 6},
            :E {:B 3}
            })
```

I want a function that creates a map as below, from the given hash-map,

```
{:A {:B 5, :C default_val :D 5, :E 7},
            :B {:A default_val, :C 4, :D default_val, :E default_val},
            :C {:A default_val, :B default_val, :C default_val, :D 8, :E 2},
            :D {:A default_val, :B default_val,  :C 8, :D default_val, :E 6},
            :E {:A default_val, :B 3,  :C 8, :D default_val, :E 3}
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from reading your example it's hard to tell exactly when you want the default value included, though there is a very common pattern of providing a set of defaults and merging the input into it so that wherever a value is given it's used and if it's not there for a particular key the default value is used:

```
user> (def default-values {:A :default :B :default :C :default :D :default})
#'user/default-values

user> (def paths {:A {:B 5, :D 5, :E 7},
            :B {:C 4},
            :C {:D 8, :E 2},
            :D {:C 8, :E 6},
            :E {:B 3}})
#'user/paths

user> (keys paths)
(:A :D :B :C :E)

user> (vals paths)
({:D 5, :B 5, :E 7} {:C 8, :E 6} {:C 4} {:D 8, :E 2} {:B 3})

user> (map #(merge default-values %) (vals paths))
({:A :default, :D 5, :B 5, :C :default, :E 7} 
 {:A :default, :D :default, :B :default, :C 8, :E 6} 
 {:A :default, :D :default, :B :default, :C 4}
 {:A :default, :D 8, :B :default, :C :default, :E 2} 
 {:A :default, :D :default, :B 3, :C :default})

user> (clojure.pprint/pprint
       (zipmap (keys paths) 
               (map #(merge default-values %) 
                    (vals paths))))
{:E {:A :default, :D :default, :B 3, :C :default},
 :C {:A :default, :D 8, :B :default, :C :default, :E 2},
 :B {:A :default, :D :default, :B :default, :C 4},
 :D {:A :default, :D :default, :B :default, :C 8, :E 6},
 :A {:A :default, :D 5, :B 5, :C :default, :E 7}}
```

Comment: Yeah, thats pretty much what I was looking for. Thanks :)